# Инициализация статических экземпляров в С++

Tags: c++

Если нетрудно, можете объяснить такую вещь: почему статические экземпляры классов должны инициализироваться во внешних определениях? То есть:

```
class X {
   static Y y(10); // неправильно
}

Y X::y(10); // правильно
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

было на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656941/why-i-cant-initialize-non-const-static-member-or-static-array-in-class).

Краткий ответ такой - так решили создатели стандарта.